# Multi session in spring security 3.1

Tags: spring-security

We develop a web application that need different authentication, in my case this is agent and member. This is the detail:

- Agent profile page is at http://my.local/spring-security-hello-world/agent/profile
- Member profile page is at http://my.local/spring-security-hello-world/member/profile
- Both of pages are filtered by springSecurityFilterChain

But i have some issues here. First I login at agent profile page, and successfully logged in. But then I open the member page, and I got HTTP Status 403 - Access is denied. The situation i want to achieve is both agent and member is able to logged in.

Here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>spring-security-hello-world</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml,
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

And this is my spring-security.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

<!-- <http pattern="/agent/login" security="none" /> -->

<http pattern="/member/**">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_MEMBER" />
    <form-login login-page="/member_login" default-target-url="/member/profile"
        authentication-failure-url="/member_loginfailed" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/member_logout" />
</http>

<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/agent/**" access="ROLE_AGENT" />
    <form-login login-page="/agent_login" default-target-url="/agent/profile"
        authentication-failure-url="/agent_loginfailed" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/agent_logout" />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="agent" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_AGENT" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>

    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="member" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_MEMBER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Notes:
In my case one user must only have one role (either agent or member only)

Answer (score 0):

If you do it in the same browser then your Agent with ROLE_AGENT is used to access page which is restricted to ROLE_MEMBER. You can add ROLE_MEMBER to your access="ROLE_AGENT, ROLE_MEMBER" to check it.

Comment: Hello freakman,
thanks for your answer.
But in my case, one user must only have one role, which is either agent or member.
Do you have any solution for my case? Thanks before.

Comment: then try to use access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_MEMBER', 'ROLE_AGENT')" for /member/** pattern, you dont change user role this way - rather allow specific url to be accessed by member or agent. Ofcourse if you consider agent to be a kind of member superset and he really should has access to member pages.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer.. but in my case agent role doesn't have authority to access member page.. can you give me another solution?

Comment: so you need to decide if he should be able to view that page or not :)